# Нет планов электропитания Windows 10

Tags: cmd, windows-10, настройка

Есть только один - сбалансированная.
Остальных нет...
Как включить отображение высокой производительности?
Это приключилось сразу после установки системы.

Answer (score 2):

Рискну оказаться Кэпом но возможно вы просто не заметили надпись "Показать дополнительные схемы"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не то, powercfg даже показывает только один план...

Comment: Советую переустановить систему ещё раз или сделать **сброс до заводских настроек.**

Comment: Нет, исключено, я уже задолбался это делать, после каждой переустановки всё так же.